# How do I zoom in the mandelbrot set using a conical slice with angle 7/20pi

Tags: python, mandelbrot

We are trying to get the correct code that zooms in the `mandelbrot` set using a conical slice of 7/20pi. This is the code we've tried, but it only gives us the `madelbrot` set with the angle and doesn't zoom in

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mandelbrot_set(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, width, height, max_iterations):
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, width), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, height))
    C = X + 1j * Y
    Z = C
    M = np.zeros((height, width))
    for n in range(max_iterations):
        Z = Z**2 + C
        M[np.abs(Z) <= 2] = n
    return M

def conical_slice(angle, max_iterations):`
    min, xmax, ymin, ymax = np.array([-2, 1, -1.5, 1.5]) * np.exp(1j * angle)
    width, height = 800, 800`
    return mandelbrot_set(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, width, height, max_iterations)
angle = 7/20 * np.pi
max_iterations = 256
M = conical_slice(angle, max_iterations)
plt.imshow(M, cmap=bone)`
plt.axis(off)
plt.show()
```

Comment: A few things that might help. You have random backticks that serve no purpose. In your conical_slice method, `min` should be `xmin`. Once you correct those issues, try reducing the number of iterations to test if you get the desired result. You should reduce the iterations because the loop in your mandelbrot_set method is overflowing. If that works for you, I would recommend looking at this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161536/python-program-that-draws-the-mandelbrot-set-fractal) to optimize your loop. Hope that helps.

Comment: When the number of iterations are reduced, the graph becomes more blurry and less accurate, and there is still no ability to zoom into the set.